# JQuery UI Datepicker inside a popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, javascript-framework

I need your help,

How would I go about creating a javascript function that would dynamically create a custom popup window with the JQuery UI Datepicker in it?

Much thanks and appreciation for all your help.

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/k4pmy/

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog({
        open: function() {
            $('#datePicker').removeAttr("disabled");
        },
        close: function () {
            $('#datePicker').datepicker('hide');
        }
    });

    $("#datePicker").datepicker();

    $("#pop_button").click(function() {
        $('#datePicker').attr("disabled", true);

        $("#popup").dialog("open");
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't too hard using jquery UI.

HTML:

```
<div id="dialog">

    <div id="datepicker"></div>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#dialog").dialog();
```

And a jsfiddle to see it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/Robodude/kgNZN/